# How to load a javascript file on the browser with a html using node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm working on a project and want to run some javascript code on client side, how can i load a javascript file for it to run on the browser and not on the server?

I've tried using sendFile(), reference the file in the html and various advice I've found online, none seem to work

I want the browser to show me in sources the html file and the javascript file that i'm referencing in the html and in the sendFile()

everytime that i try to load it i get this message from the console
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Proyectos\Walletpublic'

Javascript code:

```js
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('./public/confirm.js'));
app.get('/ide', (req, res) => {
    res.render('identification.ejs')
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + 'public'))
    console.log(req.url)
})
```

Html code:

````html
<body>
    
        <p>Complete the folowing input bars acordinly</p>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="First and last name"/>
        <input id="id" type="number" name="id" placeholder="Id number"/>
        <input id="homeAd" type="text" name="homeAd" placeholder="Home address"/>
        <input id="posCod" type="number" name="posCod" placeholder="Postal Code"/>
        <input id="phone" type="number" name="phone" placeholder="Phone"/>
        <input id="homePhone" type="number" name="homePhone" placeholder="Home phone number"/>
        <input id="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
        <br>
        <button id="ideconfi">Sumbit</button>
    </script src="../public/confirm.js">```
````

Answer (score 0):

`express.static` needs to be passed "the root directory from which to serve static assets" [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). The top line `app.use(express.static('./public/confirm.js'));` should be:

- `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

> ```
> // express on its own has no notion
> // of a "file". The express.static()
> // middleware checks for a file matching
> // the `req.path` within the directory
> // that you pass it. In this case "GET /js/app.js"
> // will look for "./public/js/app.js".
> ```
>
> app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

— another example ([from the Express static-files example on GitHub](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/3ed5090ca91f6a387e66370d57ead94d886275e1/examples/static-files/index.js))

Comment: Hi, thanks, i went and did what you said, and also corrected some erros that i had like removing the "path.join" form the res.sendFile(), when i ran it having done all that i came across a new error mesage saying: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: Seeing that i changed the order and i put first the code where i use the function sendFile and in the line bellow i put the one that uses render for rendering the html, that stopped the error messages in my terminal but when looking at the browser's console i found a 404 error relating to the file i wanted to send, the path to that file is ok